# Custom Validation in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement custom validation... My goal is that if the user's response is not "Y", or not "N", or not "Q", they loop back to the top. Otherwise break.

Both options I've tried will continue to loop even when the the correct response is given.

Here's what I've tried:
Option 1:

```
"""  Use custom validation.  """
while True:
    n_put = input('Would you like to perform a new Google image search?' + user_options())
    if n_put is not "Y" or not "N" or not "Q":
        print('Invalid response. Please read the prompt carefully. ')
    else:
        break
```

Option 2:

```
"""  Use custom validation.  """
while True:
    n_put = input('Would you like to perform a new Google image search?' + user_options())
    if n_put is not any(["Y", "N", "Q"]):
        print('Invalid response. Please read the prompt carefully. ')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: `if not n_put in ['Y', 'N', 'Q']:` or `if not n_put == 'Y' and not n_put == 'N'`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: @wwii , my question refers to multiple not-conditions. Not so much for the loop.

Comment: My bad.. possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/2823755)

Answer (score 0):

Correct Option1:

```
while True:
    n_put = input('Would you like to perform a new Google image search?' + user_options())
    if not (n_put == "Y" or n_put == "N" or n_put == "Q"):
        print('Invalid response. Please read the prompt carefully. ')
    else:
        break
```

and correct Option2:

```
while True:
    n_put = input('Would you like to perform a new Google image search?' + user_options())
    if n_put not in ["Y", "N", "Q"]:
        print('Invalid response. Please read the prompt carefully. ')
    else:
        break
```